# Able to access current location locally but not on flutter web and deployment with exception (MissingPluginException....)

Tags: flutter, web, deployment, location, geo

MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method placemarkFromCoordinates on channel flutter.baseflow.com/geocoding)
I want to access the current location of device and I am able to get it locally, but on flutter web and after deployment it gives me the exception above, how to handle this exception please.

```
Future<Position> _getCurrentLocation() async {
bool serviceEnabled;
LocationPermission permission;
serviceEnabled = await Geolocator.isLocationServiceEnabled();
if (!serviceEnabled) {
  return Future.error('Location services are disabled.');
}
permission = await Geolocator.checkPermission();
if (permission == LocationPermission.denied) {
  permission = await Geolocator.requestPermission();
  if (permission == LocationPermission.denied) {
    return Future.error('Location permissions are denied');
  }
}
if (permission == LocationPermission.deniedForever) {
  // Permissions are denied forever, handle appropriately.
  return Future.error(
      'Location permissions are permanently denied, we cannot request permissions.');
}
Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(
        desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.best,
        forceAndroidLocationManager: true)
    .then((Position position) {
  setState(() {
    _currentPosition = position;
    _getAddressFromLatLng();
  });
}).catchError((e) {
  if (kDebugMode) {
    print(e);
  }
});
return await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition();
```

}

Here I am converting the LAT LNG to Address.

```
_getAddressFromLatLng() async {
try {
  List<Placemark> placemarks = await placemarkFromCoordinates(
      _currentPosition!.latitude, _currentPosition!.longitude);

  Placemark place = placemarks[0];

  setState(() {
    _currentAddress = "${place.locality}, ${place.country}";
  });
} catch (e) {
  if (kDebugMode) {
    print(e);
  }
}
```

}